# Hebrew "URL Encoding" in R?

Tags: r, urlencode, url-encoding

I've been referred to both:

```
?URLencode
#and
?curlEscape
```

I see that both functions work great for English, but fail to provide with the proper translation for Hebrew characters.

For example, the word

> שלום

(Peace, in Hebrew)
Should be this:

> %D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%9D

But instead, both commands translate it to:

```
URLencode("שלום")
%f9%ec%e5%ed
```

What do you suggest?  (write it myself, or is there something pre-made)

Thanks, 
Tal

Update: My sessionInfo:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 2.12.0 (2010-10-15)
Platform: i386-pc-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Hebrew_Israel.1255  LC_CTYPE=Hebrew_Israel.1255   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Hebrew_Israel.1255 LC_NUMERIC=C                  
[5] LC_TIME=Hebrew_Israel.1255    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
```

Comment: Works for me too Tal. I'm running R2.12-patched on Linux in an enGB.utf8 locale.

Comment: o.k, I found the error was in the use of my local.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both URLencode and charToRaw seem to work for me...

> URLencode("שלום")
>   [1] "%d7%a9%d7%9c%d7%95%d7%9d"

Looking at the source code of URLencode

> URLencode
>   function (URL, reserved = FALSE)
>   {
>       OK <- paste("[^-ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", 
> "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789$_.+!*'(),", 
>           if (!reserved) 
>               ";/?:@=&", "]", sep = "")
>       x <- strsplit(URL, "")[[1L]]
>       z <- grep(OK, x)
>       if (length(z)) {
>           y <- sapply(x[z], function(x) paste("%", as.character(charToRaw(x)), 
>               sep = "", collapse = ""))
>           x[z] <- y
>       }
>       paste(x, collapse = "")
>   }
>
> charToRaw("שלום")
>   [1] d7 a9 d7 9c d7 95 d7 9d

Which version of R are you using?

Here is my sessionInfo()

sessionInfo()
R version 2.10.0 (2009-10-26)
 
i386-pc-mingw32 

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252  LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252  

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base  

other attached packages:
[1] preprocessCore_1.8.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_2.10.0

Comment: Hi Newuser, I tried the code- and I got the same results as before.  Something in your system seems to work while mine doesn't. that is so interesting!  I added the sessionInfo of my R to the question - could you please add yours?

Comment: Okay I've added my sessionInfo(), from above sounds like you got this to work. Best regards